# ¿Como realizar un buscador PHP y Msqli utilizando cards de Bootstrap?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

necesito saber como puedo crear una busqueda de productos que estan dentro de un index.php utilizando Cards de Bootstrap. Solo necesito tener el campo para ingresar la busqueda y un botón buscar.

Tengo una conexion.php donde se realiza la conexión a la tabla y una varibale $query donde hace la consulta con mysqli.

Lo que necesito es poder alterar esa $query para que pueda realizar la busqueda y el filtro de las cards que estan desplegadas en bloques de 6 en 6.

¿Como puedo colocar un buscardor considerando estos datos?.

dejo el index.php completo aquí

```
<?php require_once("conexion.php"); ?>
<?php
$max=6;
$pag=0;
if(isset($_GET['pag']) && $_GET['pag'] <>""){
$pag=$_GET['pag'];
}
$inicio=$pag * $max;
$query=" SELECT codigo,id,nombre,frase_promocional,precio FROM productos ORDER BY fecha DESC";
$query_limit= $query ." LIMIT $inicio,$max";
$resource = $conn->query($query_limit);
if (isset($_GET['total'])) {
$total = $_GET['total'];
} else {
$resource_total = $conn -> query($query);
$total = $resource_total->num_rows;
}
$total_pag = ceil($total/$max)-1;


?>

<?php include("cabecera.php"); ?>
<header>
    <?php include("menu.php"); ?>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron mt-5 text-center text-white">
        <h1 class="display-4">Bienvenidos a nuestra tienda</h1>
        <p class="lead">Aquí podrás encontrar las mejores rayitas con su estilo único.</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>¡Solcita tu pedido de rayitas directo a tu domilicio totalmente gratis!.</p>
        <p class="lead">
            <a class="btn btn-light btn-lg" href="registro.php" role="button">Registrate</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Catálogo<small> de Productos </small></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
                <?php if($pag-1 >= 0){?>
                <li class="page-item previous"> <a href="index.php?pag=<?php echo $pag -1?>&total=<?php echo $total?>"
                        class="page-link">&larr; Anterior</a> </li>
                <?php }?>
                <li class="page-item"> <a class="page-link"> <?php echo $inicio +1 ?> a
                        <?php echo min($inicio + $max, $total)?> de <?php echo $total ?> </a> </li>
                <?php if($pag+1 <= $total_pag){?>
                <li class="page-item next" style="float:right"> <a
                        href="index.php?pag=<?php echo $pag +1?>&total=<?php echo $total?>" class="page-link">Siguiente
                        &rarr;</a> </li>
            </ul>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<section class="catalogo mt-5">
    <div class="container">
        <?php if($total) {?>
        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3">
            <?php  while ($row = $resource->fetch_assoc()){?>
            <!-- apertura de while  -->
            <!-- Producto start -->
            <div class="col mb-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="img/<?php echo $row['codigo']?>.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="rayitas">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['nombre'] ?></h5>
                        <span class="price"><?php echo $row['precio'] ?></span>
                        <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row['frase_promocional'] ?></p>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"><a
                                href="producto.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>" class="btn btn-danger">VER MÁS</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Producto /end -->
            <?php }?>
            <!-- cierre de while  -->
        </div>
        <?php }else{?>
        <p class="error"> No hay resultados para su consulta </p>
        <?php }?>
        <!-- cierre del if -->

    </div><!-- fin de contendor -->
</section>

<?php include("pie.php"); ?>



 ``
```